# Load Stripe.js with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs, stripe.js

I'm having trouble loading Stripe.js with Require.js. My setup looks a bit like this

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'stripe': 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/?noext'
  },
  shim: {
    'stripe': {
      exports: 'stripe'
    }
  }
});
```

This actually does work, that is, I can see the script tag in the dom but when I require it it's `undefined`. Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: Does it actually export `Stripe` instead of `stripe`?  With an upper case "s"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global that stripe exports is [`Stripe`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-function) with an uppercase "S".  The `exports` needs to match the global export **exactly**, meaning case.

### This works:

```js
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'stripe': 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/?noext'
  },
  shim: {
    'stripe': {
      exports: 'Stripe' // Uppercase
    }
  }
});

require(['stripe'], function(s) {
  // Based on code from https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart
  const ss = s('pk_test_g6do5S237ekq10r65BnxO6S0');
  const elements = ss.elements();
  const card = elements.create('card');
  card.mount('#card-element');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>


<div id="card-element"></div>
```

### This doesn't:

```js
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'stripe': 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/?noext'
  },
  shim: {
    'stripe': {
      exports: 'stripe' // Lowercase
    }
  }
});

require(['stripe'], function(s) {
  console.log(s); // undefined
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>
```