# RequireJS, Stripe and dependency (Vue component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, requirejs, stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe library and I've got a vue component that is dependent on the library being loaded first.

I found RequireJS (2.3.6) and having never used it, am just wondering if I'm doing things correctly

I trie using the answer in this question but I can't get it working [Load Stripe.js with Require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976831/load-stripe-js-with-require-js)

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'stripe': 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/'
  },
  shim: {
    'stripe': {
      exports: 'Stripe',
      deps:['my-component.js']
    }
  }
});
```

I don't get any console errors but I don't see my component either

Comment: is there any reason you **needs** to require/import it this way? instead of like *loading in a script tag* or *download the script and use it directly*? (I'm not use Stripe so maybe it's limitation but I don't think so)

Comment: You usually add a script tag which is fine but my component is loaded before stripe has downloaded and run

Comment: then you don't order the scripts correct.

Comment: Yes. I know that now

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out in the end

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        form: {
            deps: [ 'stripe' ]
        }
    },
    paths: {
        stripe: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/?noext',
        form: '/js/my-component'
    }
});

require(['stripe', 'form'], function($) { 
    return {};
});
```